# How can I extract multiple pattern and create a csv file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have awk command:

```
while read -r fname
do
  part1="$(awk '/===/g {p=1; next}/***/ {exit} /^$/ {next} p==1 {gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$0);gsub("\"","\"\"",$0); print}' $fname)"
  part2="$(awk '/***/{p=1; next}/###/ {exit} /^$/ {next} p==1 {gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$0);gsub("\"","\"\"",$0); print}' $fname)"

  if [[ $part1 = *[!\ ]* ]] && [[ $part2 = *[!\ ]* ]]; then
    echo "$fname,\"$part1\",\"$part2\"" >> extracted_text.csv
  fi
done < Flist.txt
```

Where; `Flist.txt` file contains a list of file names e.g.

```
$ cat Flist.txt
file1.txt
```

and `file1.txt` has the following contents

```
This is section 1 
===
This is section 2
***
This is section 3
###
This is section 4
This is section 5
===
This is section 6
***
This is section 7
###
This is section 8
```

I'm trying to extract text between `===` and `###` then split the extracted text on `***`. The idea is to get a csv file with matched patterns like

```
file1.txt,This is section 2,This is section 3
file1.txt,This is section 6,This is section 7
```

Instead I'm getting only one match

```
file1.txt,This is section 2,This is section 3
```

NB: I'm new to `awk` and `sed`. I tried using `sed` before but in the end decided to use `awk`. But I stuck to achieve a desired output. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure bash solution:

```
while read -r fname; do
  while read -r line
  do 
    if [[ "$line" = "===" ]]; then
      track=1
      continue
    elif [[ "$line" = "###" ]]; then 
      track=0
      echo "$fname,$t" | sed 's/\*\*\*/,/g' 
      t=''
    fi

    if [[ "$track" = 1 ]]; then 
      t="$t$line"
    fi 
  done < "$fname"
done < Flist.txt > output.csv
```

Outputs:

```
This is section 2,This is section 3
This is section 6,This is section 7
```

All we're doing is looking for start and end markers whilst reading the file and setting a flag when they're encountered. After a `===` we add all the content into a variable until `###` is reached. On encountering a `###` the variable can be printed, replacing `***` with `,` to do the split.

Comment: Where can I output to a csv?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r filename; do
  awk -v OFS=',' '/^[=]+/{start=1; printf FILENAME; next}/^[*]+/{next}/^[#]+/{start=0;print ""}start{printf OFS $0}' "$filename"
done < "Flist.txt" > outfile.csv
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -v OFS=',' '/^[=]+/{                   # search for line starts with =
                      start=1;             # set variable start = 1
                      printf FILENAME;     # print filename
                      next                 # go to next line
                   }
                /^[*]+/{                   # if line starts with * 
                      next                 # skip, go to next line
                   }
                /^[#]+/{                   # if line starts with #
                      start=0;             # end of search, make start=0
                      print ""             # print newline char
                   }
                start{                     # as long as start is non-zero
                      printf OFS $0        # print output field separator
                                           # and current line/record/row
                  }
               ' "$filename"
```

> `/^[#]+/`
>
> - `^` asserts position at start of the string Match a single character present in the list below `[#]+`
> - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> `/^[*]+/` and `/^[=]+/` are similar like above regexp

**Test Results:**

```
$ cat infile.txt
This is section 1 
===
This is section 2
***
This is section 3
###
This is section 4
This is section 5
===
This is section 6
***
This is section 7
###
This is section 8


$ awk -v OFS=',' '/^[=]+/{start=1; printf FILENAME; next}/^[*]+/{next}/^[#]+/{start=0;print ""}start{printf OFS $0}' infile.txt
infile.txt,This is section 2,This is section 3
infile.txt,This is section 6,This is section 7
```

Comment: In my pc I'm getting this output `infile.txt,This is section 2 This is section 3
infile.txt,This is section 6 This is section 7`

Comment: make sure you had set `-v OFS=','`

Comment: I set but no comma for the second column

Comment: yes, it works though comma also is added in a new line

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you in same too.

```
awk '/===/{flag=1;next} /###/{flag="";print FILENAME","val;val="";next}  flag && !/^\*\*\*/{val=val?val OFS $0:$0}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too.

```
awk '
/===/{                  ##checking if a line has === in a line, if condition satisfies then do following.
  flag=1;               ##Setting variable named flag to 1.
  next                  ##using next keyword to skip all further statements.
}
/###/{                  ##Checking if a line has string ### if yes then do following.
  flag="";              ##Making variable flag as NULL here.
  print FILENAME","val; ##Printing Input_file name here by FILENAME and then comma and then value of variable named val.
  val="";               ##Nullifying the variable val here.
  next                  ##Using next will skip all further statements here.
}
flag && !/^\*\*\*/{     ##Checking conditions here if variable flag value is NOT NULL and checking if any line is NOT starting from *** then do following.
  val=val?val OFS $0:$0 ##create a variable named val whose value will be concatenating its own value(if it is NOT NULL) and will be equal to $0 if NULL.
}
' Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 0):

another awk.

```
while read -r fname; do
    awk -F"===|***" -v RS="###" -v OFS="," 
    '{gsub(/\n/,"",$0)} (NF==3){$1=FILENAME;print}' "$fname"
done < Flist.txt > output.csv
```

we set first/second patterns as field separators and third one as record separator, comma as output field separator. `gsub` removes the newlines, and after replacement with filename, print. Added `NF==3` just for not printing any last incomplete record like in the example input.